# Сохранение файлов циклично

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pillow, re

Как можно организовать генерацию нового файла каждую итерацию? В программе в образец (картинку) вставляю определенные данные из Excel.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import pandas as pd
import re
xlsx = pd.read_excel("pil.xlsx")
for ind in range(len(xlsx)):
    nme = xlsx.iloc[ind]['A52']
    surname = xlsx.iloc[ind]['A53']
    address = xlsx.iloc[ind]['A30']
    addr = xlsx.iloc[ind]['A56']
    print(addr)
    g = re.findall(r"Пензенская", addr)
    if g == ["Пензенская"]:
        addr = addr.replace("Пензенская (обл),", "")
    image = Image.open("shabl2.jpg")
    font = ImageFont.truetype("timesbd.ttf", 50)
    drawer = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    drawer.text((890, 820), "Уважаемый(-ая)" + " " + nme + " " + surname+ "!", font=font, fill='black')
    drawer.text((146, 1100), address, font=font, fill='black')
    drawer.text((1030, 981), "сентябре", font=font, fill='black')
    drawer.text((1465, 432), addr, font=font, fill='black')
    image.show()
    image.save("dn.jpg")#вот это сохранение зациклить
```

Comment: image.save(f"dn{ind}.jpg") и будет dn1.jpg, dn2.jpg и д.т.

Comment: Вау, круто и просто, спасибо! а в папочку если, это нужно слеш и название перед поставить?

Comment: save(r’Downloads\dn.jpg') или save(’Downloads\\dn.jpg')

Comment: Отпишите ответом, я отмечу